# Writing two worksheets into a new excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to to find out all the duplicates using pandas and I have managed to do so. However, there are multiple worksheets in the excel and I would like repeat the process for all the worksheets and the final excel should be all the new data without duplicates and they are placed on their individual worksheet. I am currently stuck as my code will only loop through and the result will only the last looped worksheet. Hence, it would be great if anyone can enlighten me on this issue. The below is my code:

```
final_audited_filepath = '<file_path>\\test12.xlsx'
x1=pd.ExcelFile(final_audited_filepath)
writer=pd.ExcelWriter("<file_path>\\test123.xlsx")
for sheet in x1.sheet_names: #scan for the number of worksheets in the excel
    data=pd.read_excel(final_audited_filepath, sheet_name=sheet)
    data_first_record= data.drop_duplicates(subset=['Reference ID','Check Description'], keep="first")

    data_first_record.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=sheet)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write more than one sheet in the workbook or excel file using Pandas, you need to use an ExcelWriter object,

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as f:
      df1.to_excel(f, sheet_name='sheet 1')
      df2.to_excel(f, sheet_name='sheet 2')
```

After dropping the duplicates, create separate data frames df1, df2 and so on.. for different worksheets and try the code above.

Click here to check [Pandas to_excel Documentation Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: Hi, prasun thank you for the idea, i have managed to write my data into a separate worksheet. thank you!